# A moving point on the unit circle which you cannot define how long it have traveled

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p$ be a moving point on the unit circle $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $[0,1]$ denote the time axis and $p$ can be seen as a continuous function $p:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$.

I guess you can compute how far $p$ traveled during $[0,1]$ for almost all cases.

Is there some example of $p$ such that you can not define such amount by integration or the amount is infinite?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suspect you mean how *far* it travelled? How long would usually refer to time, and if I understand the question correctly, it travelled for $1$ unit of time by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continuous function $p:[0,1]\to[-1,1],t\to t\sin\frac1t$ is not of [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation), so a moving point described by this function could not be said to have travelled some finite distance.